# Proof of reflexive, symmetric and transitive when m | n

Tags: relations

I'm trying to write proofs or counterexample using the definition of divides only for each operation (reflexive, symmetric or transitive) in the following:
The relation V on Z+ for all m and n in Z+, mVn <-> m | n.

I'm familiar with the set operations as:

V is reflexive if for all x in A, xVx.

V is symmetric if for all x, y in A, if xVy, then yVx.

V is transitive if for all x, y and z in A, if xVy and yVz, then xVz.

I'm just not sure how to approach divisibility her. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I mean, this is just definition crunching. $m\mid m$ for all $m$ obviously, $m\mid n$ and $n\mid m$ only if $m=n$, i.e., it is anti-symmetric, and $a\mid b$ and $b\mid c$ implies $a\mid c$.

Comment: not symmetric:  $2\mid4$ and $4\nmid2$

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You have reflexive property because every positive integer divides  itself.

You do not have  symmetry because for example $5|10$ but $10\not | 5$

You do have transitive property because if $x|y$ and $y|z$ then $x|z$

You can fill in the details of the proof for each part.

This relation is not an equivalence relation.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @Val Thank you for your attention and understanding.